# image overriding when scrolling in list view in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'am loading more than 100 images using API in list-view ,each row height is "225" . rows are clickable that popup a model . my problem is when I scrolling the list-view each time images get replaced. I can see when i scroll, new row comes up with old image and in one second time new images replace that old image.
I tried some caching method XAML view, but i didn't help me . can someone help me to go through this issue.

Comment: This is a caching problem.  Try using FFImageLoading, or be more specific about what "tried some caching method" means

Comment: i used   CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"

Comment: that makes it reuse previous cells, which would cause exactly the behavior you're describing

Comment: so FFImageLoading helps me top fix the issue

Comment: @Maalik Due to the count of Cells is too much and each of them contains an none too small size of Image. Although using `CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"`, the Cells will not shows the new content immediately . Here `FFImageLoading` is a good solution.  If not using `FFImageLoading` or other Image Library , you'd better load cells in pages .Such as when scroll to bottom will load more , then next page of cells will show .